# Segmentation fault related to ofstream

Tags: c++, io, segmentation-fault, fstream

I'm stumped on this one...can't seem to find a solution anywhere...

I have a class SAR composed of SARdataPoints.  SAR calculates analysis values related to stock prices contained in SARdataPoints.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include "SARdataPoint.h"
#include "SAR.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

array<string, 10> files = {"/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/ASPS.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/AZO.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/CNP.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/COST.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/CVS.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/DBP.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/DGL.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/JJP.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/ORLY.csv",
                           "/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/PHYS.csv"};

SAR SAR1 = SAR(); // initialize SAR object

ofstream output; // initialize output file
output.open("/home/reechee/Documents/Cpp/HW3/output.txt"); // open output file

for(auto& f : files)
{
    cout << "Now reading file: " << f << '\n';
    SAR1.parse(f);
    SAR1.initComp();
    SAR1.calcSAR();
    SAR1.printSARfile(output);
}

output.close(); // close output file
return 0;

} // end main()

void SAR::printSARfile(std::ofstream& file)
{
    file << std::setw(8) << "Date" << " ";
    file << std::setw(8) << "High" << " ";
    file << std::setw(8) << "Low" << " ";
    file << std::setw(8) << "EP" << " ";
    file << std::setw(8) << "Alpha" << " ";
    file << std::setw(8) << "Trend" << " ";
    file << std::setw(8) << "SAR"  << " " << '\n';

    for(auto const& d : data)
    {
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getDate() << "  ";
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getHigh() << "  ";
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getLow() << "  ";
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getEP() << "  ";
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getAlpha() << "  ";
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getTrend() << "  ";
        file <<  std::setw(8) << d.second.getSAR() << '\n';
    }
}
```

If I comment out printSARfile(output), it runs without error.  With it there a seg fault is thrown.  I know the calculation functions run fine as I can print everything to the console.  If I try to write to the file with something like

```
output << "TEST";
```

that works fine, but only if that line is directly in main(), not if it's in one of the for loops.  It's gotta be something simple I'm just ignorant to.  If I drop in some output.ios::good() in there here and there, it's good to go every where between the file open and close.

Sorry for the wall-o-text.  SAR::parse() included below by request.

```
//The function parse() uses the Boost Tokenizer library to parse the date, high,
//and low values into SARdataPoint objects.
void SAR::parse(std::string filepath)
{
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > Tokenizer;
std::string line;

std::ifstream file(filepath);

if (file.is_open())
{
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
       Tokenizer tok(line);

        for(Tokenizer::iterator iter = tok.begin(); iter != tok.end(); ++iter)
        {
            int currentIndexInt;
            std::string currentIndexStr;

            //something in here was duplicating the final digit of the date,
            //second call to erase is a truncation work-around
            if(std::distance(tok.begin(), iter) == 0 && *iter != "Date")
            {
                currentIndexStr = *iter;
                currentIndexStr.erase(std::remove(currentIndexStr.begin(), 
                                                  currentIndexStr.end(), '-'));
                currentIndexStr.erase(currentIndexStr.size() - 1);
                currentIndexInt = std::stoi(currentIndexStr);
                this->addDataPoint(currentIndexInt);
            }

            if(std::distance(tok.begin(), iter) == 2  && *iter != "High")
            {
                this->data[currentIndexInt].setHigh(std::stod(*iter));
            }

            if(std::distance(tok.begin(), iter) == 3 && *iter != "Low")
            {
                this->data[currentIndexInt].setLow(std::stod(*iter));
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
}
```

Here's the [full git repo](https://github.com/reeecheee/SAR) (sorry for the delay, never used git before).

Comment: It's possible one of your earlier calls is corrupting something, and it's only being "detected" because of the output routine.

Comment: Shoot...I hope not.  The reason I turned to outputting to a file is that the console in my IDE (Anjuta) isn't large enough to output all these lines (~5000); it only shows the most recent ~200 lines printed.  Do you see any other logical way to pull all the output from the terminal?  I can't find anything in the Anjuta settings to extend the capacity of the terminal output.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out a part of printSARfile(), especially the for() loop ?  I'd bet on some rogue pointer in one of the getters.

Comment: commented out the for loop with the getters...no dice, still throws the seg fault

Comment: Can you provide more code, i.e. the class SAR, especially the parse-method. Anyway the whole source code for SAR and SARdatapoint would be good.

Comment: Checking that the file successfully opened before trying to write to it is also generally considered wise.

Comment: SAR::parse() code added.

Comment: Please provide the whole class SAR and SARdatapoint (on some external site).

Comment: Added a link to the full source.

Comment: @reechee: Could you attempt to reduce the code down to using __one__ input file, and then include that file as well?

Comment: I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: I boiled the code down to just a single input file instead of looping through all of them.  Still same segfault situation.  I also added a CSV file to the git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding that if I initialized the ofstream object within the for loop that iterates through the CSV files, things worked out ok.  I was not able to locate the cause of the segfault, but this was a functional workaround.  In doing so, however, the file was just rewritten from scratch in each iteration, so I had to eliminate the for loop entirely and just manually run the code specifically for each file, one at a time.